# Assign variable in IF Javascript

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I have the following code:

```
if (images[i].parentNode) {
 var parent = images[i].parentNode;
}
```

When doing this I am accessing the parentNode twice. I am wondering if it's possible/correct to do this:

```
if (var parent = images[i].parentNode) {
 // here I can access parent.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:** Did you try it? :) What you have isn't legal JavaScript and the interpreter won't accept it because the `var` keyword is not accepted there.

If you don't want to access `parentNode` twice, simply assign it to a variable:

```
var parent = images[i].parentNode;
if(parent) {
    ...
}
```

It doesn't matter in which block `parent` is defined because JavaScript doesn't have block-level scoping.

You *can* however, do this:

```
if(parent = images[i].parentNode) {
   ...
}
```

But the problem is that `parent` will belong to the global namespace (if you haven't defined it previously). So you can do this:

```
var parent;
if(parent = images[i].parentNode) {
    ...
}
```

But as you can see, it's not very different from what I suggested earlier so you're not really buying your self much with this and it's also liable to cause confusion to anyone reading your code (even you!) because it's an unfamiliar construct.

Comment: That said, if the `var` in the condition is removed, the syntax is valid.

Comment: @MattBall Good point; I'm actually editing to mention that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local scope for your variable:

```
(function(){
   var parent = images[i].parentNode;
   // here I can access parent.

   console.log(parent); //logs parent variable
})();

console.log(parent); //ERROR parent not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
var parent = images[i].parentNode;
if (parent) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```